# Java Swing - Change JComponent opacity from mouse listener

Tags: java, swing, opacity, jcomponent, mouselistener

Pretty much like the title says - I've got a JPanel, and I'd like to have it at 90% opacity if inactive, and full opacity if moused over.

I've got the separate components working - the mouse over and out is OK and I can change the opacity from overriding the `paintComponent` method, but I suppose I'm having trouble with the connection between the `MouseAdapter`  and the `paintComponent`.

It seems there's probably a really easy way to do this - any tips?

*(BTW sorry left the code at home so no example for now :( unless it's not quickly solvable then I'll throw some code up tomorrow.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are overriding the `paintComponent` method, you should be able to add an opacity variable to the `JPanel` extension. Modify this in the `MouseAdapter` (using mutators). Then refer to this variable in the overridden `paintComponent` method to determine how to paint.

Comment: +1
In this case I'd prefer the panel class to be self contained and not expose unnecessary public Interfaces, as every information is essentially present in the class itself.
But that may be a matter of taste.

Comment: Agreed. I was unsure how the code was originally structured, so I was giving a more general explanation. Your example is how I typically would implement something like this (and how it should be, for clarity).

Comment: Although the two answers are similar, I'm going with this answer, since I think the children of this component will need to access that same variable (will test later).

Answer (score 3):

If you override the paintComponent method already, I'd suggest you make the MouseAdapter an anonymous inner class of your Panel and let it manipulate a private boolean flag.

```
public class FadingPanel extends JPanel
{
    private boolean active;

    public FadingPanel()
    {
        createMouseAdapter();
    }

    private void createMouseAdapter()
    {
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            // your mouseadapter code here toggling the active flag
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
         if(active)
         {
              super.paintComponent(g);
         }
         else
         {
              // your semitransparent painting code here
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is also a viable solution, probably more effective depending on the situation

Comment: +1 for the answer, but this is one of the few times where overriding paint may be preferred over paintComponent, especially if the component involves children and borders (such as a JButton).

Comment: @Hovercraft - actually, it does have several children, one of which is indeed a JButton.  I'm not quite clear on your meaning - are you saying, if children then override `paint`?  Related: does `paint` also paint the children?

Comment: Really, the best way to solve this is to run to your on-line store and buy [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) by Haase and Guy. It is the best resource for problems just like this one.

Answer (score 3):

Shoot, I don't have the Haase and Guy book with me, and I don't remember the way they recommend to code for translucent components, but I guess overriding either paint or paintComponent work except that overriding paint will show the effect on child components from the get-go.  For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class OpaqueJPanels {

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      mainPanel.add(new OpaqueJPanel(false, "Override paintComponent"));
      mainPanel.add(new OpaqueJPanel(true, "Override paint"));

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Opaque JPanels");
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class OpaqueJPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int OJP_WIDTH = 250;
   private static final int OJP_HEIGHT = OJP_WIDTH;
   private static final Composite TRANSLUSCENT_COMPOSITE = AlphaComposite
            .getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.4f);
   private static final Composite NON_TRANSLUSCENT_COMPOSITE = AlphaComposite
            .getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f);
   private boolean overridePaint;
   private boolean transluscent = true;

   public OpaqueJPanel(boolean overridePaint, String title) {
      add(new JButton("Button"));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            transluscent = false;
            getParent().repaint();
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!OpaqueJPanel.this.contains(e.getPoint())) {
               transluscent = true;
               getParent().repaint();
            }
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(OJP_WIDTH, OJP_HEIGHT);
   }

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      if (!overridePaint) {
         super.paint(g);
         return;
      }
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      Composite composite = transluscent ? TRANSLUSCENT_COMPOSITE
               : NON_TRANSLUSCENT_COMPOSITE;
      g2.setComposite(composite);
      super.paint(g);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      if (overridePaint) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         return;
      }
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      Composite composite = transluscent ? TRANSLUSCENT_COMPOSITE
               : NON_TRANSLUSCENT_COMPOSITE;
      g2.setComposite(composite);
      super.paintComponent(g);
   }
}
```

I also found that it was better if I repainted the JPanel's parent component rather than the JPanel itself.